# Check if query will cause duplicate row

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I have a database with a primary key on the first column (words)
I want to trim the trailing and leading ends of my data, but I get an error that this causes duplicate data

EX: ' David ' will become 'David' and that is already in the database

Is there anyway to compare what I already have in the database to my Select statement (without spaces) and remove any that will cause a duplicate row?

Comment: Can you ask the database (using a SELECT) if there exists a conflicting row before you issue the INSERT?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Func(PK),count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY Func(PK)
HAVING Count(*)>1 ;
```

Where Func() is whatever you're using to clean up the PK column spaces

Example:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(PK)),count(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY LTRIM(RTRIM(PK))
HAVING Count(*)>1 ;
```

Example2: (as suggested by Martin in the comments)

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY LTRIM(PK) ORDER BY LTRIM(PK)) as rn 
FROM tab) 
DELETE FROM cte where rn > 1;
```

Comment: Thank You, but how would I then convert it into an update or delete statement?

Comment: @Dmandy, whats your final objective? The above query will identify which all rows will cause a duplicate, what do you wish to accomplish next?

Comment: Delete those rows, so that the trim query does not cause any errors

Comment: So if you have 4 rows 'David',1 ' David',2 'David ',3 and ' David ',4 , you want to delete all 4?

Comment: I want to leave one of the 'David' and delete the rest, the second column doesn't matter here

Comment: Try example 2...

Comment: Trailing spaces aren't significant and you don't need the join. The example 2 can be simplified to `WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LTRIM(PK) ORDER BY LTRIM(PK)) as rn FROM tab) DELETE FROM cte where rn > 1;`

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting.. didnt realize you could do that :)